# Swift animateWithDuration Completion Runs When Modal View is Pushed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, core-animation

The following code animates one of my views and has a completion block

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: timeToShow, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.75, initialSpringVelocity: 2, options: nil, animations: {
                self.murmurComposeTextView.frame = oldFrame
                self.showNewMurmurView.frame = self.getLeavingBGFrame()
                }, completion: { finished in
                    self.pickerButtonBig.enabled = true
                    self.pickerButton.enabled = true
                    self.isShowingNewMurmur = false
                    self.murmurComposeTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
            })
```

If I present a modal view while this is running, then quickly dismiss it, I notice 2 things:

1. The animated hasn't completed, but proceeds as usual (which I want).
2. The completion block has already run, as pickerButton is enabled, self.murmurComposeTextView.becomeFirstResponder has run, etc. This is what I don't want.

Does anyone know if this behaviour is on purpose, or if I have a bug, and if there's anyway to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The "finished" Bool that is passed into the completion block indicates whether or not the animation was actually completed when the completion block is called.

So you can check that Bool to determine what you want to do. Something like:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: timeToShow, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.75, initialSpringVelocity: 2, options: nil, animations: {
            self.murmurComposeTextView.frame = oldFrame
            self.showNewMurmurView.frame = self.getLeavingBGFrame()
            }, completion: { finished in
               if (finished) {
                    self.pickerButtonBig.enabled = true
                    self.pickerButton.enabled = true
                    self.isShowingNewMurmur = false
                    self.murmurComposeTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
               } 
        })
```

The docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:completion: